# Refused to evaluate script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning to develop a Browser Action extension for Google Chrome, and have split up javascript functionality into multiple files. In the popup.html file, script resources are defined like

```
<script src="js/Identity.js"></script>
<script src="js/View.js"></script>
```

View.js needs to call into methods of the object exposed from Identity.js, and passes a callback function to be notified when the process is completed. However, it appears Chrome would break execution.

> Refused to evaluate script because it violates the following Content
>   Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"

From what i understand, Google states that policy is to prevent arbitrary strings to be evaluated into an executable block of logic. However I am passing actual functions between my objects so i'm not too sure what must be corrected here?

```
IdentityObj.Process = function (params, callback) {
  doSomeWork();
  setTimeout(callback(true), 1000); // break here
};
```

From the View object, an example would be

```
View.loginClick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.loggingInState();

        var emailAddr = $('#emailAddr').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        IdentityObj.login(emailAddr, password, this.loginCallback.bind(this));
    };

View.loginCallback = function(success) {
        if (success) { this.usageState(); }
        else { this.errorState(); }
    };
```

Comment: `callback` does not return a function. If that's not the case, show your real code.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. callback is a function from the caller object, which this method will call once it is done with the work.

Comment: Show the definition of `callback`.

Comment: View side code sample added. thanks.

Comment: Now, the connection with the original code...?

Comment: In this scenario, the View would call for IdentityObj.login(). The IdentityObj would perform its backend login process before calling the View's callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague sported the problem and explained it, so now I understand what you were referring to.

I was *executing* the callback function direct in the setTimeout() definition, so setTimeout() receives the result of callback(true) instead of the callback itself. That would then require an eval and thus triggering the Chrome security policy.

The execution of callback() has to be wrapped in a function declaration.

```
IdentityObj.Process = function (params, callback) {
  doSomeWork();
  setTimeout(function(){callback(true)}, 1000); // break here
};
```